# Launch Mac app on OS load won't work

Tags: macos, operating-system, plist, launch-agent, launchctl

I am trying to create a plist file, to put within the LaunchAgents of the users Mac. This plist I will use to make sure it opens a specific application every time the Mac turns on or the user logs in. To my knowledge I am pretty sure the plist should work as it is right now, but it doesn't. Whenever I restart my Mac or log out and log in again, nothing happens.

To make it slightly easier to compare with other Mac's, I am trying to open the regular Calculator app, of which is on all Mac's.

To list what I have currently done is, make the plist below and named it `open.plist` Along with that I have placed it in the LaunchAgents folder, which is within the library folder of my Mac.

Here is the current plist of mine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
   <key>KeepAlive</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Basically the idea is to have this plist within the LaunhAgents and then have it load an app within the Application or Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchAgents should only be used for background services. It isn't an appropriate way to launch applications at login.

To launch an application at login, [add it as a login item](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html). Login items can also be added manually using the "Users & Groups" system preference pane.